# CSS selector attributes does not work when adding style to component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am having this React component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./style.module.css";

export interface IMenuButtonProps {
  name: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
  btnColor?: string;
}

const MenuButton: React.FunctionComponent<IMenuButtonProps> =
  function menuButton({
    name = "Unamed Button",
    onClick,
    btnColor,
  }: IMenuButtonProps) {
    return (
      <button
        className={styles.btn}
        type="button"
        onClick={onClick}
        style={{ color: btnColor }}
      >
        {name}
      </button>
    );
  };
export default MenuButton;
```

and this CSS file:

```
.btn {
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: chartreuse;
}
```

The hover selector attribute does not work when adding:

```
 style={{ color: btnColor }}
```

Border and height works fine. I suspect it changes color for both btn and btn:hover.
Anyone knows what happens or how to change only btn and not btn:hover?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you add color like this

`style={{ color: btnColor }}`

you are adding styles inline to your HTML, so it is more important than css classes. This is a common problem when mixing CSS classes with inline CSS.

To solve problem convert inside component 'btnColor' prop to some css class and then you can combine classes for example with library called 'classnames'. Also I like to specify in props interface what colors are availble in component. For example I would write it like this:

```
export interface IMenuButtonProps {
  name: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
  btnColor?: 'red' | 'blue' | 'black';
}
```